# divergent and bounded sequences

Tags: numerical-methods

For the sequence $Z_n= ncos(n\pi/4)$. I know $S={-inf, 0, inf}$. I know this sequence has no limit, but can I say $Z_n$ is bounded? Or it is divergent to $-inf$ or $inf$?

Comment: $Z_n$ is not bounded. Look at what happens when $n=4k$, where $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: It is also not divergent to $-inf$ and $inf$, correct?

Comment: What does $S$ mean?

Comment: It means subsequential limits of $(S_n)$

Comment: If it has subsequences that diverge it is not bounded.

Comment: It is neither divergent to $\pm \infty$ as it has subsequence that converge.  It simply does not converge and it is unbounded.

Comment: I get it! Thanks!